# Gas usage by the OpenSea ERC-721 example code

Tags: tokens, erc-721, nft, gas-price, opensea

I am currently trying to mint some ERC-721 non-fungible tokens to the OpenSea website.

I am following [this tutorial](https://docs.opensea.io/docs/getting-started) and have got everything working on the testnet. My collection has been minted on Rinkeby and I am now ready to move on to the main net.

[This](https://docs.opensea.io/docs/7-launching-on-mainnet) is the step of the tutorial I am now on.

The tutorial code I have been using is found [here](https://github.com/ProjectOpenSea/opensea-creatures) and, running on the testnet I can see that three steps involve gas fees: The [migration step](https://github.com/ProjectOpenSea/opensea-creatures/blob/master/migrations/1_initial_migrations.js), the [deployment step](https://github.com/ProjectOpenSea/opensea-creatures/blob/master/migrations/2_deploy_contracts.js) and each [minting step](https://github.com/ProjectOpenSea/opensea-creatures/blob/master/scripts/mint.js).

I've not submitted many smart contracts before and I've never really fiddled with gas prices. I know I probably have to set a gas price based on the current standard gas but I'm not sure how.

---

My question is this:

Where in the [`opensea-creatures' example code](https://github.com/ProjectOpenSea/opensea-creatures) is the gas price set for each of the three of the steps I mentioned above? Should I change these prices or is there something automatic which handles this for OpenSea? (I understand OpenSea's has a lot of workarounds so people don't have to pay gas when minting but think these probably don't apply here)

Also, on a side note; is gas fee usually specified in Wei units?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The gas price is set by the signer. If you are connecting this code to Geth, MetaMask or a similar wallet, you can set the gas prices there.

Comment: Okay I see... So just to confirm: I just change the gas price in metamask and then whatever smart contract I deploy using my metamask details will just use that gas price? Thank you!

Comment: This confuses me because when I deploy to rinkeby the deployment step uses a gas price of 20 gwei whilst the minting steps use a price of 1 gwei - shouldn't they be using the same price from metamask though?